# Godot 3.4.3 Export error 'apksigner' returned with error #1

Tags: java, android, godot, android-sdk-manager

I'm getting this error on linux

```
'apksigner' returned with error #1
```

This only happens when I try to export an apk for the play store. I have made the new key for the store and I have tried exporting the game to a new folder. When I do and turn off the export with debug I get the error apksigner returned with error #1

I have uninstalled all JDKs before 30 and just have that one installed. I have Java 11 (as I read somewhere else that 12 doesn't work) I am not sure if I need to wipe the android folder clean in my godot project or not. I have created the release keystore using

keytool -v -genkey -keystore mygame.keystore -alias mygame -keyalg RSA -validity 10000

and put that in for my release in godot under release under the keystore area. I used the -alias (business name) for the Release User, and put in a password when asked for keystore password and used that in the Release Password. I also changed the mygame.keystore to (gamename).keystore. Do I need to remake this keystore each time I change the SDKs? Each attempt to export for release has failed.

Answer (score 2):

Considering this was all new installs for the sdks and the android studio, I'm guessing that me logging out and logging back in fixed it. I tried just about every suggestion out there so I'm not 100% on if that was all that was wrong, but that seems to be how I got it to finally work and get around the error. Mind you I did a lot of other things that I read helped other people before I restarted and got it working so again other suggestions may also be valid.

I later got the same error when trying to overwrite the apk. This doesn't work. I had to trash it and make a new apk. I also tried to make an aab and realized I didn't have JDK 11 installed. Both work fine now. NOTE: Google play doesn't accept apks anymore. Must make an aab file.

Comment: Ah, that could be environment variables. Processes get a copy of them from the parent process when they start, so they might not see changes to PATH, JAVA_HOME, ANDROID_HOME, or ANDROID_NDK_ROOT. And you solve that by closing everything and opening again. Well, that or some of the installing and uninstalling needed to restart to finish something.